# Why don't C++03 file streams accept string constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, c++03, library-design

Why does the following code compile in `C++11` and does not in `C++03`? *(both `gcc` and `cl`)*

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::string t("Hello");
    std::ofstream out(t);
}
```

Why don't the `C++03` streams accept `std::string` as the constructor parameter? *Was this decision based on something or did it happen accidentally?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code fails when compiled with a strictly conforming C++03 compiler because the constructor that takes a `std::string` was only added in C++11.

As to the question, "was it based on something smart", as the interface *was* added, it can be inferred that there was no technical reason for it to be omitted.

It's an addition of convenience as, if you have a `std::string`, you can always call `.c_str()` to get a C string suitable for use with the old interface. (As the documentation in C++11 says , the constructors that take `std::string` have *exactly* the same effect as calling the corresponding constructor which takes a `const char*` with the result of calling `.c_str()` on the string.)

Answer (score 5):

As I recall, this was discussed on c.l.c++.m some years ago, and Andrew Koenig (I think it was Andrew, anyway) said it was actually brought up during some meetings, *but* the idea of accepting a `string` was quickly conflated with the idea of accepting a `wstring` as well, and from there turned into a discussion about support for internationalized character sets in file names, and ... shortly after that the whole idea was dropped because it had opened a big can of worms nobody was prepared to deal with right then.

Answer (score 2):

They had simply forgotten about adding the `string` constructor in C++03. Now that's fixed. This time round other things were forgotten, like `make_unique`. There's always something more that one could have done. C++03 also forgot to specify default arguments for function templates, which are now included.

*Edit:* As @Charles says, it may not be a literal "forgetting", but rather, it's something that clearly *should* be there, but just hadn't been specified for some reason or another. Further examples are given by `std::next`/`std::prev`, which are a great relief, and `std::to_string` and `std::stoi/d/ul/ull`, which again make perfect sense, but nobody had gotten around to specifying them until this time round. There isn't necessarily a deep reason for their previous absence.

Comment: I'm not sure that "forgotten" is really appropriate. Iostreams are one of the oldest parts of the standard library and the first standard was a large slice of codifying existing practice. As C++ has involved, the `std::string` interfaces feel more like an omission, especially when teaching C++ as a new language. They help iostreams form a more consistent part of the whole library.